# как вставить одно значение в несколько полей input используя js?

Tags: javascript

есть селект

```
<select id="main-sel" onchange="document.getElementById('js-result').value = this.value">
     <?php foreach ($list as $key => $value){
         echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
     }?>
</select>
```

и есть много инпутов:

```
<input type="text" id="js-result">
<input type="text" id="js-result">
....
<input type="text" id="js-result">
```

Как видно из кода, мне надо чтобы при выборе элемента селекта выбранное значение вставлялось во все имеющиеся инпуты с `id="js-result"`. Но оно вставляется только в первый инпут. Как вставить во все?

Comment: Ответ Вам уже дали, но на будущее имейте ввиду, что содержимое атрибута `id` должно быть уникальным в пределах одного документа, а классы Вы можете использовать для объединения элементов по визуальным и (что в Вашем случае более важно) по функциональным критериям.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<select id="main-sel" 
  onchange="var myValue=this.value;document.querySelectorAll('.js-result').forEach(item=>item.value=myValue);">
<option>One</option>
<option>Two</option>
<option>Three</option>
</select>

<br/>

<input type="text" class="js-result">
<input type="text" class="js-result">
<input type="text" class="js-result">
```